# CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate' showing in evert new terminal

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I initially had miniconda3 installed. I tried installing anaconda but later removed it. After removing anaconda, every new terminal I open gives the following lines

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'o initialize your shell, run

```
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

Currently supported shells are:

- bash
- fish
- tcsh
- xonsh
- zsh
- powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

```
$ echo ". /home/ss/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

or, for all users, enable conda with

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/ss/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

```
$ conda activate
```

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

```
$ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

```
export PATH="/home/ss/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^

I tried all the commands mentioned above it works in one terminal. opening a new one returns the same problem. I have sourced the ~/.bashrc

Comment: Your `.bashrc` file may have leftovers from your previous installation of Anaconda. You may have to manually edit `.bashrc` to get rid of them.